# Deleted pictures keep coming up

Tags: google, samsung-galaxy-note-4

I am trying to import my pictures from my Samsung Note 4 to my laptop. But I have a problem with the whatsapp images folder. The pictures showing on my mobile screen are not the same shown on my pc once connected. Some deleted pictures or repeated ones are taking the place of others by having the same name. And they are imported instead of the ones I didnt delete.
I don t know if I made myself enough clear. But am gonna lose my pictures if I don t find a solution.
Thank you.

Comment: In what way are you importing? Kies?

Answer (score 1):

Try using u file manager on your phone to sort the pictures into one folder, then copy that folder, if the issue remains the same..
Try compression (zip/rar/7zip/tar) and Extract on PC